# Present view controller modally from two source controllers, with navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm searching for what I believe must be the simple solution to showing (modal) the same destination view controller (an edit screen - with navigation controller and nav bar) from two source view controllers: 1) the root list, and 2) the view item screen.

Here's the sort of thing I mean:

[image: Storyboard]

My understanding is that the relationship segue between nav controller and destination VC can only be connected to one source VC? Every time I fixed one, the other broke.

All my attempt to implement prepare for segue generated fatal init coder errors.

Removing the navigation controller and implementing two @IBSegueAction func's got the segues working but removed the required navigation bar (and its save, cancel buttons).

I'm sure I'm missing something simple to elegantly create this workflow. But I can't find it.

I'm using Xcode 14.3 and building in UIKit.

Comment: This is rather confusing... in your screen-cap, which controller is which? Is the left-most table view already in a navigation controller? Are you trying to select a row, show a "view item" controller, and then allow that to "switch to edit mode"?

Comment: Hi @DonMag - Yes you are right. The left most table view is already in a navigation controller. It's + bar item should lead modally present the add/edit VC. A tap on a cell shows the view VC, the edit button of which should modally present the add/edit VC again. In each case the add/edit VC needs to be prepared slightly differently.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to `present` the controllers instead of `push`, which would keep the navigation bar and navigation functionality?

Comment: Hi @DonMag - sorry that may be me using terms incorrectly. In both cases I'm trying to use a show segue (I think this is recommended by apple for when content is editable) instead of a push segue.

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to handle this type of navigation / flow.

One approach...

Instead of embedding your "Edit" table view controller in (another) navigation controller, add a `UINavigationBar` to the table view controller.

Now you can `present` it from

- either the "+ add new" button on your "List" table view, or
- from the "Edit" button when viewing the item

This is basically how it would look:

[image]

Really, really quick example project: https://github.com/DonMag/NavApproach

Comment: Thanks DonMag. Been trying to implement this approach but running in to the same problems all over. 1) My Edit VC will not allow me to add a UINavigationBar for some reason, so I'm forced to embed it in a view controller. 2) Any attempt to use an IBSegueAction func to present modally throws a Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented error, unless I use the relationship segue between the navigation controller and the edit VC - but i can only use that in one of the two instances. 3) I tried to replace the IBSegueAction with a prepare for segue implementation, but no joy.

Comment: @Phil - personally, I wouldn't do things this way -- I stick mainly to code and do not use Storyboards / Segues. However, I put together this really, really quick example project that you can download, run, inspect, etc: https://github.com/DonMag/NavApproach

Comment: Wow, thank you. Your project is an approach I've tried, but I just keep getting Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented errors despite the relationship segues working fine. 

Since apples swift curriculum taught UIKit, that's what I've been working with. I get the feeling I need to relearn based on SwiftUI. I'm happy to do it, but I hate being defeated by something that should, I'm sure, basically work!

Comment: @Phil - I've only looked at SwiftUI enough to get a basic understanding of it... but, the main thing I learned was that I hope I never have to work with it!

Comment: @Phil - *"I just keep getting Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented errors"* ... do you mean you're getting those errors with my example project?

Comment: no no your project works perfectly - I think because the view controllers are all declared in the same swift file and the data is known to all of them rather than being passed to and fro. I cant find a single resource online that features this kind of user journey - so it feels like a dead-end.

Comment: @Phil - couple things... 1) has nothing to do with classes being in the "same swift file" ... 2) I have no idea how you're managing your data (I *assume* you're saving it somewhere), so I just used a quick Singleton ... 3) the error you're getting is NOT an internal iOS error... it is being generated by ***your*** code. Search your project for `fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")` and you'll see why.

Comment: Oh I absolutely agree with you - my code is doing something wrong. But what's wrong appears to be related to how I'm passing data/setting properties when segueing.

Comment: @Phil - I you post a [mre] to somewhere like GitHub I expect I could give you a fix in very short order.

Comment: you're very kind to offer, and persevere. I've recreated the basic models, viewcontrollers and segues here: https://github.com/grin-phi/Seguetest - before i even get to adding the functions to update arrays etc, I've already got the initializer errors - nor do I have working nav on the final VC.

Comment: @Phil - going straight from List to View, the `@IBSegueAction` was not connected correctly, so it was never running. I deleted that segue, re-made it, re-connected it and no more `fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")`. I **do** suggest skipping the intermediate nav controller... I think you were having trouble adding a navigationBar because you cannot add one if the table view controller is *already* in a navigation controller. If you add me as a "Collaborator" to your GitHub repo I can update it with new branches. My GitHub ID is the same as here - DonMag

Comment: Added you DonMag. I'll be very interested to see what you do. I could only ever get 2 out of 3 segues working simultaneous. Fixing the third broke one of the others.

Comment: @Phil - ok... you should be able to pull the repo with two new branches -- "Fix" and "Suggest"

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. Your solution worked perfectly. Unfortunately, I couldn't establish the specific difference in how the segues were applied that led to them working. I would like to mark this as solved but wondered if you wanted to post an additional solution with the basics of what you did for future readers?